# How can I evaluate simple math expressions in es?

Tags: shell, unix, exponentiation

[For reference, I'm using this version of the shell](http://wryun.github.io/es-shell/).

I'm looking to evaluate a math expression containing exponents. How can I do so? `expr` isn't available in [es-shell](/questions/tagged/es-shell), and neither do the double parends work (as they do in other shells).

The expression I want to evaluate is `2^69` (2 to the 69th power).  I've tried with both `**` and `^` for exponentiation.

I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use an external calculator, hopefully pure [es-shell](/questions/tagged/es-shell) code.

Comment: I read through the man page for `es`, and I don't see any reference to arithmetic. It appears you cannot do math in pure `es`.

Comment: That's too bad. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Unix shells delegate math to some other command. `bc` is probably available on your machine, since it's [a POSIX utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/bc.html). Invoke it from es like this:

```
; echo `{echo '2 ^ 69' | bc}
590295810358705651712
```